# Share Menu extension to Copy to Clipboard

Tags: macos, copy-paste

Is there an app or a script that can be added to macOS **System Preferences > Extention > Share Menu**

[image: Screenshot of the Extensions preferences pane]

So you can use the Share Menu to copy to macOS Clipboard?

[image: Screenshot of the Share Menu > Copy to Clipboard]

It would be very helpful when the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is not working, for example, when you are creating a screenshot with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>. You edit something, like adding an arrow. Currently, when you press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> instead of copying the entire screenshot to the clipboard, it copies the lastly modified and currently selected arrow.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Screenshot to clipboard is cmd/shift/opt/4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an app called Shareful that adds share menu extensions:

- Copy to Clipboard
- Save to Downloads
- Open in Application

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/shareful/id1522267256?mt=12